# Can iOS notification push a file

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

Can I somehow send a whole file with a push notification on iOS, or send a notification to a device to download a file from a server.

The device NEEDS to do that on it's OWN, without user interaction and I need it to work without updating the app in the store.

So is that possible? If not any advices/alternatives are welcome.

Comment: I updated my answer with an important warning about push reliability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I somehow send a whole file with a push notification on iOS

While you could serialize your file and send it, push notifications are [limited to 2kB](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1).

> or send a notification to a device to download a file from a server.

You can do it with ["Remote notifications" background mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5).

> The device NEEDS to do that on it's OWN, without user interaction

The previous option will work, unless your user manually killed your app.

> I need it to work without updating the app in the store.

You will need to update your app. At least to turn on "Remote notifications" background mode and handle the incoming data.

---

**EDIT:**
And don't forget that **Push Notifications are NOT RELIABLE**!
A Push notification can be delayed or even never distributed. That's why you should **NEVER** rely on it to achieve any critical work.

Comment: Thanks, for the comment. I will re-think if I should use push notifications. However the information is not that critical. It can be delayed a few hours to a day with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot push an entire file given that a push notification is limited in size to 2KB (256 bytes in pre-iOS8). It is possible to cause an app to execute code using a push notificiation.

Depending on the type of app, it might be able to ocassionally poll your server and retrieve information. All in all, you will certainly have to make changes to your app's code, thereby requiring you to publish a new version on the App Store.

Comment: What you are suggesting is having a background service running and checking for changes in the server every now and then. If there is a new file then it downloads it?

Comment: Push notifications are now limited to a 2kB payload. See my answer for references.

Comment: And it's possible to trigger a data download with the "Remote notifications" background mode.

Answer (score 0):

*Can I somehow send a whole file with a push notification on iOS*

**NO**

You can learn more about Push Notifications and get answers to other questions here

[How we leverage iOS push notifications](http://blog.layer.com/how-we-leverage-ios-push-notifications/)